# Fail to take screenshots with Selenium WebDriver using Java when a JUnit test fails

Tags: java, junit, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am using Java with Webdriver, and I am having problem with taking screenshots with failed test.

My jUnit test:

```
....
public class TestGoogleHomePage extends Browser {

....
@Test
public void testLoadGoogle() {
//this test will fail
}
}
```

My Browser class:

```
public class Browser {
protected static WebDriver driver;

public Browser() {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
}

.....
@Rule
public TestWatcher watchman = new TestWatcher() {

    @Override
    protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver)
                .getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(
                    "C:\\screenshot.png"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            System.out.println("Fail to take screen shot");
        }
        // this won't work
        // driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

    @Override
    protected void succeeded(Description description) {
     ....
    }
};

@After
public void closeBrowser() {
    driver.quit();
}

}
```

The execution of the test will result in the following error message (part of the error message):

> org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: The FirefoxDriver cannot be used    after quit() was called.

Looks like it is complaining about my @After method.

I have tried to change the Browser class to be:

```
public class Browser {
protected static WebDriver driver;

public Browser() {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
}

.....
@Rule
public TestWatcher watchman = new TestWatcher() {

    @Override
    protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver)
                .getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(
                    "C:\\screenshot.png"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            System.out.println("Fail to take screen shot");
        }
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Override
    protected void succeeded(Description description) {
     ....
     driver.quit();
    }
};

}
```

And the above codes work fine. But I don't want to quit the driver there because there might be something else I want to clean up after each test run, and I want to close the browser in the `@After` method.

Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: Why don't you have a `@Before` method that re-instantiates your `WebDriver` class?

Comment: Because in my TestGoogleHomePage class, I use public TestGoogleHomePage() {
  super();
 } to initialize my Webdriver class, and if I place \@Before on this constructor, it will complain that @before is at illegal location. But seems like it will always re-initialize the Webdrive class for every test even without the \@before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because of the following code:

```
@After
public void closeBrowser() {
    driver.quit();
}
```

The `driver.quit()` is attempting to close the browser after EVERY test; and it is getting executed before the call-back methods of your `TestWatcher`.  This is preventing `TestWatcher` from getting a handle of the `driver`. Try using a more restrictive life-cycle annotation like `@AfterClass` or `@AfterSuite`.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your reply. I have changed the `@After` to `@AfterSuite`, and the screen shots are saved properly. But the opened browsers are not closed, why is that? Thanks.

Comment: @nzsquall The driver = new FirefoxDriver(); should preferably done in the counter-part method of driver.quit(). For example, if you're doing driver.quit() in AfterSuite, you can do the new FireFoxDriver() bit in the BeforeSuite.

Comment: I upgrade the webdriver to the latest version 2.37 and it works!